# gnuplot ytics like "1000k" possible?

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to have ytics looking like "0k", "5'000k", "10'000k", and so on. However, when I try scientific notation (e.g., "%5.0s%c"), I get "0M", "5M", "10M" instead.

Any idea how to implement it in gnuplot?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what code you have?

Comment: set ytics format "%5.0s%c".   Or do you want me to post the whole script (I thought it has no other relevant information)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not sure that I understand what you're going for here, but maybe something like:

```
set ytics format '%gk'
plot 'datafile' u ($1/1000.):2
```

Or if you're plotting a function `f(x)`:

```
plot f(x)/1000.
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I wanted! I ended up with 'set ytics format "%'.0fk"' and '($1/1000):2'